# How to make WinPE bootable for both UEFI and Legacy at the same time?

Tags: windows, boot, bios, winpe

I'm preparing wim images that contains both win 7 and win 10 images. I will give them to technicians and they will check if the computer will be win 7 or win 10, if it'll be win 7 then they will go to bios settings and change UEFI to Legacy etc.. I want to automate this process.

Is there a way to make it possible for WinPE to boot both Legacy and UEFI at the same time?

Comment: You can't boot UEFI and CSM at the same time, but preparing a bootable USB-stick that is capable of UEFI and CSM boot depending on what is available is possible e.g. using the tool "Rufus".

Comment: Windows 7 supports UEFI.  Why are you going to unnecessarily use MBR for Windows 7? The default WinPE already supports both by the way

Comment: @Robert The only way to do that with Rufus is by selecting the non-default / not recommended "DD" option. By default it makes one or the other as that is its reason for existing according the the developers own words (they really dislike the hybrid ISO concept).

Answer (score 1):

If you follow [Microsoft's instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive) on creating a bootable WinPE drive, it will be bootable from both Legacy and UEFI BIOS.

The `\boot\` folder contains the Legacy boot files while `\EFI\` contains the UEFI boot files.

As far as using different wim files for Legacy / UEFI:

```
wpeutil /UpdateBootInfo
reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control /v PEFirmwareType
```

If the above command returns `0x1` PE booted into BIOS (Legacy) mode, if `0x2` UEFI. Based off that, you could write a simple script that selects the wim you with to use.

Comment: The problem the author will have is being able to use both the Windows 7 and Windows 10 `install.wim` on the image.  You can put multiple images, of the same version of Windows, within a single windows image without an issue.  However, trying to create a multi-image media is something else entirely.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks! I'll update my answer.